# Sorting the values in a java ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: java, sorting, concurrenthashmap

I have the following code for sorting a ConcurrentHashMap:

```
ConcurrentHashMap<String,String> text = new ConcurrentHashMap<String,String>();
.... 
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(text.values());
Collections.sort(list);
```

Which throws a NoSuchElementException:

```
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException
        at library.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:1232)
        at library.ArrayList$ListItr.next(ArrayList.java:1263)
        at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:120)
```

And I can't work out why. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post a full source required to reproduce problem?

Comment: Do you have another ArrayList on your classpath?  "library.ArrayList" doesn't seem correct.

Comment: `library.ArrayList` is definitely not the standard `ArrayList`, which exists in `java.util.ArrayList`. Make sure you're using the correct libraries and double-check your classpath.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [java api](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html)

> **NoSuchElementException**
>   Thrown by the nextElement method of an
>   Enumeration to indicate that there are
>   no more elements in the enumeration.

I tested the following code locally

```
ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> t = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, String>();

List<String> al = new ArrayList<String>(t.values());
Collections.sort(al);

System.out.println("no bugs");
```

(with Eclipse jdk 1.5) I get the expected output.  I also ran my local test after putting some key-value pairs into the ConcurrentHashMap and had no problems.  Based on my successes, it would seem that one (or both) of the following is causing the discrepancy between our results.

A) We are using different class implementations (I use java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap, java.util.List, java.util.ArrayList from jdk 1.5)

B) You are modifying the contents of `ArrayList` or `ConcurrentHashMap` WHILE an iterator is iterating through the contents of said object.  Does the exception occur while running the sort?  My best guess is another thread is messing with your `ArrayList` (since `ConcurentHashMap` is supposed to be thread safe) while you are sorting.

Answer (score -1):

It's unnessary to create a new ArrayList for sorting,thus,you can do like this :

```
ConcurrentHashMap<String,String> text = new ConcurrentHashMap<String,String>();
List<String> textList=text.values(); //unmodifiable List here.
Collections.sort(textList);// it also can sort.
```

:EOF

Comment: Using Java7 this fails with java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Values cannot be cast to java.util.List