# Sort concurrentHash Map with threadsafty

Tags: java, multithreading, collections, concurrenthashmap

I am using 'concurrentHashMap' in my 'multithreaded' application. i was able to sort it as describe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3507861/sorting-the-values-in-a-java-concurrenthashmap). but since i am converting hashmap to a list i am bit worried about the thred safty. My 'ConcurrentHashMap' is a static variable hence i can guarantee there will be only one instance of it. but when i am going to sort it i convert it to a list, and sort then put it back to a new concurrentHashMap.

Is this a good practice in multi-threading enlivenment?

Please let me know your thoughts and suggestions.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Concurrency aside, there's no such thing as a sorted HashMap.  You can copy the values to a list and sort the list, but when you take the list values and put them back into the HashMap, they go back into hash order.  (There's LinkedHashMap, but there's no concurrent version of that.)

Comment: @Wyzard - so if i sorted it according to my comparator and create a new concurrentHashMap and put it inside a loop from the list it should be in a sorted way right?

Comment: If you put the elements from the sorted list into a new ConcurrentHashMap and then iterate over that map, you'll find that the elements are in the same order as in the original ConcurrentHashMap, *not* the order they were in the sorted list.

Comment: And if you look more closely, you'll find that they're sorted by the numbers returned by their hashCode() methods.

Comment: @Wyzard - Thanks for the explanation. my object inside the hashmap need to sort according to the two attributes of its own. so i wrote a comparator to do so. once i go through your comments i doubt that i need to write the equals() and the hascode() methods in that object by using the both attributes. am i correct?

Comment: hashCode() is not for sorting, and if you try to implement it as a comparator, it probably won't produce evenly-distributed values so your hashmap will not work efficiently.  You'll also make other developers think you're insane.  **Hashmaps are not sorted.**  The whole point of a hashmap is that it arranges the elements for efficient lookup, *not* for predictable iteration.  If you want a map that sorts its contents with a comparator, use ConcurrentSkipListMap like John Vint's answer recommended.

Comment: @Wyzard I don't even think you'll find the objects are sorted by their hashCode()s. HashMap and ConcurrentHashMap each have a method `int hash(int)` which hashes the keys' hash, specifically to guard against classes that don't produce evenly-distributed values. That's not part of the spec, of course -- but that's how it is in the openjdk.

Comment: @yshavit, and even without that, hashcodes that fall within the same bucket wouldn't necessarily be sorted relative to each other.  I should've included words like "probably" and "approximately" in my earlier statement.  Hashmaps don't make *any* guarantees about iteration order.

Comment: @Wyzard True -- I was just pointing out that the standard implementations go out of their way to ensure that the hashCodes() are probably *not* approximately sorted (and as with any undefined behavior, even a statement like that comes with tons of caveats.)

Answer (score 6):

You should use a [ConcurrentSkipListMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html).  It is thread-safe, fast and maintains ordering according to the object's comparable implementation.

Comment: Thanks for the turn around. is there any example i can get about ConcurrentSkipListMap? i have never used it.if you have something please let me know. i will start working on it.

Comment: @Sam You should take a look at the Comparable interface.  If each key of the Map is of type Comparable each put will automatically order the map itself.  It has similar functionality and time complexity of a TreeMap.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't change it a lot and all you want is to have it sorted, you should use a **[TreeMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html) ** wrapped by a **[Collections.synchronizedMap()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedMap%28java.util.Map%29)** call

Your code would be something like this:

```
public class YourClass {
  public static final Map<Something,Something> MAP = Collections.synchronizedMap( new TreeMap<Something,Something>() );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. i have never use this kind of map. i will search for some examples and see..if you have some examples please let me know.will go through the TreeMap API now. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> My 'ConcurrentHashMap' is a static variable hence i can guarantee there will be only one instance of it. but when i am going to sort it i convert it to a list, and sort then put it back to a new concurrentHashMap.

This is not a simple problem.

I can tell you for a fact, that using a ConcurrentHashMap won't make this thread-safe.  Nor will using a `synchronizedMap` wrapper.  The problem is that sorting is not supported as a single atomic operation.  Rather it involves a sequence of Map API operations, probably with significant time gaps in between them.

I can think of two approaches to solving this:

- Avoid the need for sorting in the first place by using a Map that keeps the keys in order; e.g. use ConcurrentSkipListMap.
- Wrap the Map class in a custom synchronized wrapper class with a synchronized `sort` method.  The problem with this approach is that you are likely to reintroduce the concurrency bottleneck that you avoided by using ConcurrentHashMap.

---

And it is worth pointing out that it doesn't make any sense to sort a `HashMap` or a `ConcurrentHashMap` because these maps will not preserve the order into which you sort the elements.  You could use a `LinkedHashMap`, which preserves the entry insertion order.

Comment: Thanks Stephan. but what happens if i use the code inside the 'Synchronized' block? the reason is i need to make sure about the concurrenthashmap containing only sorted list with the thread safty.thinking of sorting values before inserting to the hashmap.

Comment: @Sam - doing the sort inside a synchronised block only helps if each and every other use of the map also synchronizes on the same object.  And THAT is likely to result in a concurrency bottleneck ...